# Why did my cat attack my eyeball when I was sleeping?

Tags: safety

I have a nine-year-old cat who sleeps next to my pillow every night since he was a kitten. Last night, he attacked my right eye when we were sleeping. He then went on to sleep. I was lucky, my eyeballs weren't hurt but my eyelid now has claw marks.  I am afraid to have him sleeping with me again.

Why did my cat attack my eyeball when I was sleep?

Comment: Does your cat otherwise attack (or try to play) when you are sleeping?  My first instinct is that the location of the scratch on your eye is mainly bad luck or coincidence.  I don't know of any evidence that domestic cats intentionally target the eyes.

Comment: @Meg i agree it must have been bad luck cats do normally not hit you in the face,the only time my cat have done something simmilar was when she hit me on the lip to wake me she had caught a mouse and i obviously had to see it :) i started to bleed and all.

Comment: I don't know if you can call it coincidence becoz this is the second time it happened. First time, he attacked my husband's eye and went on to sleep. This only happened in the middle of the night when everyone is asleep.

Comment: If you dream your eyeballs jerk. This is called REM(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_eye_movement_sleep) maybe this triggers your cat to catch this "prey like thing" under your eye lid?